# OkHttpProfilerInterceptor not working after updating target sdk version to 30

Tags: android, android-studio, okhttp, android-sdk-tools

I have added OkHttpProfilerInterceptor for intercepting HTTP requests.
But since I upgraded my Target SDk to 30, it's crashing here.

```
if (HelperMethods.isDebug()) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addInterceptor(new OkHttpProfilerInterceptor()).build();
        AndroidNetworking.initialize(getApplicationContext(), client);
    } else
        AndroidNetworking.initialize(getApplicationContext());
```

Error Log

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected Android API level 21+ but was 30
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform$Companion.buildIfSupported(AndroidPlatform.kt:370)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform$Companion.findPlatform(Platform.kt:204)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform$Companion.access$findPlatform(Platform.kt:178)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.kt:179)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.kt:211) 
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.kt:204)
```

I am not sure why this happening, because it was working fine when my target version was 29, since playstore doesn't allow sdk 29 now, I am stuck over here.

I tried updating the okhttp library version but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed in 3.14.7 and 4.9.1

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6569